# Force continuous output with Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, output, flush

I have a codeigniter controller method that is supposed to run for ever (endless loop) - it checks some databases and does some data maintenance.

On certain events I want to output (echo) one line to the browser, so that my output would look somewhat like this:

```
Service loop started
...task xxx done
...done something else
...found xyz
...task xxx done
...task xxx done
...task xxx done
...done something else
```

Now Codeigniter 3 buffers the output and waits for the method to finish before it sends the output to the browser. How can I force CI3 to flush the output?

Here is my code (simplified):

```
public function dowork()
{
  $counter = 0;   // I am using a counter to test this with 1000 loops
   while ($counter <= 1000)
   {
     // do something here....

     $this->output->_display(); // this doesn't seem to work

     flush();            // I took this from the PHP manual
     ob_flush();         // but it doesn't send the output either

     $counter++;

   }
}
```

[***Note*** It might be important to add that I am running on Apache 2.4 / Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with PHP 5.6]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide something to output. The functions `set_output($output)` and 
`append_output($output)` are used for this purpose.

```
public function dowork()
{
  $counter = 0;   // I am using a counter to test this with 1000 loops

  while($counter <= 1000)
  {
    //In addition to a "default" output, you should set headers too.
    $this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('text/html')
        ->set_output("Service loop $counter started"); 

    // do tasks here

    if($xxx)
    {
      // undocumented function append_output() appends data onto the output string.
      $this->output->append_output("task xxx done");
    }

    if($xyz)
    {
      $this->output->append_output("found xyz");
    }

    //tasks done, send to browser
    $this->output->_display();

    $counter++;
  }
}
```

Do you realize this method will block the user from doing any other task until it completes?

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. From the manual: `Calling this method manually without aborting script execution will result in duplicated output.`